# Parentheses and comma in Liquibase context

Tags: liquibase

Can I mix () and , in a liquibase context attribute?

```
<changeSet id="xxx" author="mhz" context="(c1 or c2 or c3 or c4) and blackbox-test" >
```

works fine for me. However, if I use the more compact form

```
<changeSet id="xxx" author="mhz" context="(c1,c2,c3,c4) and blackbox-test" >
```

I get *Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot parse context pattern (c1*.

I am using Liquibase 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I just grep'ed the current source code and the class ContextExpression is where this message is coming from. Here is [the block of code](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/3.5.x/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/ContextExpression.java#L104-L115):

```
while (expression.contains("(")) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\((.*?)\\)(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new UnexpectedLiquibaseException("Cannot parse context pattern "+expression);
    }
    String parenExpression = matcher.group(2);

    parenExpression = ":"+String.valueOf(matches(parenExpression, runtimeContexts)).toUpperCase();

    expression = matcher.group(1)+" "+parenExpression+" "+matcher.group(3);
}
```

The error message you included said `Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot parse context pattern (c1.` with a period after `c1`, which is strange because your inpuit string (which is `expression` in this block of code) does not have a period in it.

There are [some tests for this class](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/3.5.x/liquibase-core/src/test/groovy/liquibase/ContextExpressionTest.groovy) also, but I don't see anything that covers your example.